# How to delete all screenshots before a test run while doing a cypress visual regression

Tags: regression, cypress

I was doing a visual regress where I am comparing two screenshot for the same URL but in different environment. I am taking the screenshot from production and comparing it with the snapshot taken from test env. So can anyone tell me how to delete all stored screenshot from previous run before starting a test run. I want to add it in cypress defaults or as an option so I dont have to do it manually each time

```
        describe('Visual regression for elements in hotnews section', () => {
          beforeEach(() => {
          cy.viewport("macbook-15")

          })
          it('Take the screenshot of entire hot-news section in prod env', () => {
          cy.visit("https://www.thequint.com/hot-news")  

          cy.get("#container").first().matchImageSnapshot('Hot-news',{coverage: 'fullpage'})
          })
          it('compare the screenshot of the hotnews section with the one taken in beta env', () => {
          cy.visit('/hot-news',{failOnStatusCode: false})
          cy.get("#container").matchImageSnapshot('Hot-news',{coverage: 'fullpage'})
          })
          })
```

Answer (score 8):

I hope you have to set the option `"trashAssetsBeforeRuns": true` in `cypress.json` file, which will delete the `screenshotsFolder` and `videosFolder` before each test run.

Hope this helps.